# How to change the API response before send to the client ?

Tags: node.js, restify

I'm developing a middle-ware which send request to third party URL and fetch the data and then my middle-ware process on that data and then send to the client.

I want to find a way to update the API response and then send to the client in restify.

E.x.

```
var obj = {
    uid:123,
    name:test
}
```

When I'll send res to the client it should be like this

```
 var obj = {
    sid:123,
    username:test
}
```

I need this type of changes from server side and not to write same code in all AP. I need global way to solve this issue.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve?

`var obj2 = { sid: obj.sid, username: obj.name }`

Comment: I need to set like server will automatically update the value instead of I write code in all API.

Comment: For Example if server found that , In res sid is there then server will update it from sid to uid.

Comment: In short , Before send response to client the changes should be apply as above I explain. Still you didn't get my point then let me know...

Comment: @YakiKlein Yes this is what i want to send to client side, but i want to know if there is way to do this using [restify](http://restify.com/) because i have 100 of api's to modify response and give back accurate response to front end.

Answer (score 0):

What is possible to do is to create a JSON that maps from server-side key names to client-side key name.

Ex.

```
const keyMap = {
    sid: sid
    name: username 
}
```

Then iterate your objects and create from it a new object with requested keys.

```
 let obj2 = {};
 Object.keys(obj1).forEach(k => {
     obj2[keyMap[k] || k] = obj1[k];
 });
```

You will still need to call a function that will convert the objects from each API. Alternatively, override the `res.json` method to first call the convert function and then call the original `res.json` method.